# Virtual host Apache redirecciona mal

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

Tengo 2 vitual hosts en ubuntu, tengo instalado Apache 2.4.2, tengo activados los dos vitual host y agregados los dominios a /etc/hosts pero cuanto intento acceder a dominio1.test me redirige a dominio2.test

Virtual host 1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@gmail.com
    ServerName dominio1.test
    DocumentRoot /home/jose/www/dominio1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /home/jose/www/dominio1/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual host 2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@gmail.com
    ServerName dominio2.test
    DocumentRoot /home/jose/www/dominio2

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /home/jose/www/dominio2/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dominio1.test
127.0.0.1       dominio2.test

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: tengo el mismo problema alguien que me pueda ayudar cree dos virtual host en apache pero al tratar de ingresar a el segundo host me envia a el primero pareciera que apache no encuentra el segundo host que siempre me muestra el primero y los dos estan habilitados y configurados

Answer (score 0):

En `<VirtualHost *:80>` específica cada nombre de dominio `<VirtualHost dominio1:80>` y `<VirtualHost dominio2:80>`

Comment: no funcionó, también probé con <VirtualHost dominio1.test:80> y<VirtualHost dominio2.test:80>

Comment: era el maldito caché del chrome, probé en modo incógnito y funciona.